# How many times - or where - should I use a "container" class on css in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

But I am not really sure whether the idea is that I put one `<div class="container">` around my whole page, or whether I should nest them. I think I see both in various examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to figure out the same thing -- I *think* the idea is that `.container` is intended to be a fixed width div -- 940px in the default css -- whereas `.container-fluid` is, well, fluid. At least that's what I've sussed from looking at the css and the (sparse) [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts).

Answer (score 3):

Anywhere you want a div that is centered with a width of 940px. It is also used in the navbar to position elements. There are no hard and fast rules.

If it was only meant to be used once they would have given it an id instead of a class